# SQL Inner Join 2 Tables: AVG based on Group

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables: movies and cast with the following schema:

```
movies: | id | name | score |
cast:   | movie_id | cast_id | cast_name | 
-- cast.movie_id corresponds with movies.id
```

I want to find the cast with the highest average movie scores with some conditions (movies with score < 40 should be ignored, and selected cast should appear in > 2 movies). This is what I have now:

```
SELECT c.cast_id, c.cast_name, AVG(m.score) AS average_score FROM movies AS m
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM cast GROUP BY cast_id HAVING COUNT(cast_id) > 2) AS c
ON m.id == c.movie_id
GROUP BY c.cast_id
HAVING m.score >= 40
ORDER BY AVG(m.score) DESC, c.cast_name ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

But when I check the result, e.g. for some cast, the output average score is 100.0, but the scores for his movies are like 100, 100, 85. May I know where I got wrong with the above SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can phrase this as:

```
SELECT c.cast_id, c.cast_name, AVG(m.score) AS average_score 
FROM movies m INNER JOIN
     cast c
     ON m.id = c.movie_id INNER JOIN
     (SELECT c.cast_id
      FROM cast c
      GROUP BY c.cast_id 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 2  -- Only need `COUNT(DISTINCT c.movie_id)` if a person can be in one movie more than once
     ) cc
     ON cc.cast_id = c.cast_id
WHERE m.score >= 40
GROUP BY c.cast_id, c.cast_name
ORDER BY average_score DESC, c.cast_name
LIMIT 10;
```

Notes:

- The subquery is used to count the movies for a given cast member.
- The additional `JOIN` to `cast` is needed to get the id and name.
- The `HAVING` clause is unnecessary.

Comment: I suppose under line 4 there should be another "INNER JOIN" right?